# GeoServer doesn't recognize imagery in GeoPackage

Tags: raster, geoserver, geopackage

I'm currently trying to upload a GeoPackage containing raster images to a GeoServer (v2.13) instance with the GeoPackage extension. The file contains ~425 layers but after I add the file to the server's data directory and attempt to add it to the data stores (GeoPackage Mosaic), I get a vague error message:

`Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: null`

I'm wondering if this is an existing error somewhere but I can't seem to find anything current in the GitHub repo issues or elsewhere on the net. The images are perfectly in QGIS 3 and in Python.

See the screenshot below (ignore the locale setting weirdness):
[image]