# Error creating GeoPackage raster store in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have a Float32 (32-bit floating point) heightmap GeoPackage file, that I am trying to create a coverage store with GeoPackage(Mosaic) plugin. Is there any limitation with Float32 data?

gdalinfo reports that its a valid GeoPackage file, georeferenced to EPSG:4326 and has expected values for Corner Coordinates, Pixel Size, Origin,and Metadata.
I have also used the GPKG validator to confirm that the gpkg is valid.
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/validate_gpkg.py

When I try to create a store, the WebUI responds with the same error as that reported here:
[GeoServer doesn't recognize imagery in GeoPackage](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288476/geoserver-doesnt-recognize-imagery-in-geopackage)

GeoServer Log output:

```
2019-08-09 14:10:00,430 INFO [org.geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:data/acme/Poland/poland_bk_htmap_LZW.gpkg
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: null
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:184)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:61)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.getFilteredItems(GeoServerDataProvider.java:202)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getFilteredItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:200)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.size(GeoServerDataProvider.java:220)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.updateMatched(GeoServerTablePanel.java:597)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:592)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:182)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:96)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$1.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:111)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:110)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSuccessfulSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.store.AbstractCoverageStorePage$1.onSubmit(AbstractCoverageStorePage.java:139)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1309)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742)
    at org.geotools.geopkg.mosaic.GeoPackageReader.<init>(GeoPackageReader.java:106)
    at org.geotools.geopkg.mosaic.GeoPackageFormat.getReader(GeoPackageFormat.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1523)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1469)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor560.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:126)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:100)
    ... 131 more
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge the GeoPackage reader has been tested only with RGB/RGBA images.

In GDAL the support for floating point data is available since version 2.3 (see https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html#tiled-gridded-coverage-data), however this is not part of the core GeoPackage standard, which only foresees PNG and JPEG tiles to be used, see http://www.geopackage.org/spec121/index.html

Support for gridded data has been added into an optional extension of GeoPackage:
http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/17-066r1/17-066r1.html

GeoServer at the moment can only deal with simple GeoPackages, support for gridd data ones would be nice, code contributions or sponsoring would be welcomed.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. How about the same data (float32) in GeoTIFF format. Does GeoServer (v2.15.2) support it fully? I am seeing a bit of instability there. The first couple of times, I was able to preview it with OpenLayers & as PNG. But a couple of days later, it just displayed a black box for the same data.

Comment: What you are seeing as instability is probably just the automatic mapping of the floats into a scale from black to white, considering the pixels in the area you requested. You should create a custom style with a colormap instead. See the documentation: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look.